# Completely delete SD card files partition/format

Tags: partitioning, mount, permissions, sd-card

I'm having issues doing a legit format and partition of an SD card on Ubuntu I have plugged in.

I've been using fdisk, mkfs, Disks, and GParted but they have all only 'done' the task and not deleted the files.

I'm using fdisks and mkfs initially to delete,make,and later put files onto the SD card to make a bootable Os for another system.

It works fine but the files I had on it before STAY there and won't come off.

I need to use sudo to run the commands so I can't modify any of the files once mounted. I've tried chown and chmod and then rm -rf but none  of them work to delete any files.

The only way it seems to delete my files is to do a complete zero erase of the drive which takes about 15minutes.

Is there a better way to do this? I wouldn't even mind graphically deleting the files but I am not allowed to as it  won't give me permission.

Thank you

Comment: you'll need to use `sudo` to chown and chmod as well if you don't have permissions to the files. Please [edit] your question to include the full command and the results of same to clarify exactly what your issue is. thank you for helping us help you!

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you a more drastic solution:

1. `sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/mmclbk0` (or whatever blkid lists)
2. `mkfs.vfat /dev/mmclbk0`

If you'll keep the same errors maybe there are some hardware issues or system permission issues and I can't help you